# Rolling Dice in python cookbook

Tags: python, dice

I am reading the Python cookbook and have a problem to understand this [rolling dice case](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-cookbook/0596001673/ch17s14.html)

This solution is :

```
import random

def dice(num, sides):
    return reduce(lambda x, y, s=sides: x + random.randrange(s),     
    range(num+1)) + num
```

In my understanding, the `+num` in the end is to eliminate the `0` produced by `randrange(s)`. Can I write the code as:

```
import random

def dice(num, sides):
    return reduce(lambda x, y, s=sides: x + random.randrange(1,s),
    range(1,num+1))
```

Does this looks nicer?

Comment: BTW: what is the lambda argument "y" for ?

Comment: This code looks horribly over-engineered. Unless I'm missing something, I'd drop that cookbook.

Comment: It looks like it was written by someone who doesn't know about the `sum` function.

Comment: The point isn't to *eliminate*  the `0` so much as to compensate for it by converting a sum of `num` numbers in the range `0` to `side-1` to a sum of numbers in the range `1` to `sides`.

Comment: I guess you're using an older edition of that book, which was originally published in 2002. Python has come a long way since then.

Comment: I've read that article now and, as far as I'm concerned, it's garbage. What difference does it make that dice faces add to 7? There's nothing special about dice that makes this different from generation of random numbers normally, within a range. I'd wash this code from my brain if I were you.

Comment: That book was written 16 years ago. The third edition (which has different authors) doesn't seem to mention `reduce` at all. In something like `Lisp` or `Clojure` it would be important to master that approach. In modern Python, trying to use it is more often than not borderline grotesque. It might be a better use of time to study from a book of more recent vintage.

Comment: FWIW, here's a more modern version that works on Python 2 & 3: `sum(random.randint(1, sides) for i in range(num))`

Comment: Thanks all for the comments. Would someone like to  recommend a nice book to read for Python beginner?  I can program but not with Python so much.

Comment: Found this one. https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-cookbook-3rd/9781449357337/